# Error while update package lists via apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

I have an error while trying to update package list by typing: `sudo apt-get update`:

```
...
Get:26 http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free i386 Packages [1 828 B]
Fetched 12,5 kB in 3s (3 129 B/s)                 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.opera.com_opera-stable_dists_stable_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.opera.com_opera-stable_dists_stable_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.opera.com_opera-stable_dists_stable_non-free_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)tory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.opera.com_opera-stable_dists_stable_non-free_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
```

And I have no files at this path.

How to fix problem?

Comment: Looks like that error is only in one ppa. Do you really need it? If not, you could just remove it.

Comment: What happens if you remove everything in `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` (`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`) and try again? Does the error message change?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I tried execute `sudo apt-get clean` (it has same effect). And it has no effect - error still appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue, but had to combine things from above.

Step 1: Remove Opera

```
sudo apt-get purge opera-stable
```

Step 2:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Step 3: Install Opera

```
sudo apt-get install opera-stable
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem at my system. 
Just started the update again after i did:

```
    bash$ sudo apt-get update
    bash$ sudo apt-get clean
    bash$ sudo apt-get update
    bash$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Stopped for a while as opera download took almost 2 Minutes for its 50MB file (at a location with theoretical download bandwith of 2,5MB/s), but after a while all went trough without any error left.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the ways of solving the problem, I'll tell my steps how I resolve the problem:

1. Remove all from `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` (`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`);
2. Uninstall `opera` (`sudo apt-get purge opera-stable`);
3. Update repository list (`sudo apt-get get update`) - *finished without errors*;
4. Install `opera` (`sudo apt-get install opera-stable`);

I don't know why clean partial diractory didn't resolve problem without reinstall `opera`, but it works now.