# Error while "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: apt, updates

I was trying to run the command `sudo apt-get update`
It showed me the following error.

```
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)

E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable Release
```

How to solve this error?

**Contents of** `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ x$

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Comment: please post the contents of  `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Comment: @TejasLotlikar I have google-chrome.list, google-chrome.list.save, nodesource.list, nodesource.list.save and vscode.list inside `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @karel i have no idea how to get the output from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I went to that directory all i can find are some files.

Comment: @karel Please see the edited question. I have included the `/etc/apt/sources.list` contents, but i am no sure which ones are duplicates

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step 1: Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to open `terminal`

Step 2:Run the command

```
sudo apt clean
```

Step 3: Update the package list

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 4: Remove all files from `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` (if exists)

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

Step 5: Remove the lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Step 6:  Downloading the `vscode` package from this link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868

Step 7: `cd` to the download directory in which the file is downloaded(probably `Downloads`) and run the command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: While trying to remove its giving error `rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*': No such file or directory`. But the directory is there. Why is it showing no files or directory?

Answer (score 1):

According to the answers from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876066/error-while-update-package-lists-via-apt-get-update), to solve this problem:

1. Remove all from /var/lib/apt/lists/partial (`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`)
2. Uninstall vscode (`sudo apt purge vscode`)
3. Run the update `sudo apt update`
4. Install vscode again by :
   . Downloading the .deb package from [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
   . Go to the download folder by running `cd ~/Downloads`.
   . Install the package by running: `sudo dpkg -i code_1.41.1-1576681836_amd64.deb` (the filename may change accorfing to the version number).

To remove the duplicate warning:
1- run `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
2- comment the line that has `http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable Release`
3- save and exit

Comment: While trying to remove its giving error rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*': No such file or directory. But the directory is there. Why is it showing no files or directory?

Comment: Your duplicate warning fix actually fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many suggestions but following solution worked for me.

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list*
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this can be helpful for others with similar problem.